# How to image a floppy on Win98/Dos for Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, ms-dos, floppy, windows-98

I need to make an image of a floppy disk containing DOS drivers to use in VirtualBox.  Is there to do it in the Windows 98 command line environment?

Comment: The odds are better on the OS that's hosting VirtualBox. What are you using? It's a one-liner on Linux/Mac.

Comment: @Ken - MacBook Pros don't have floppy drives. That kinda kicks out the one-liner option.

Comment: I tried WinImage, and it worked great, but it's trialware.  I'd still like if someone could come up with a script that could do the WHOLE operation in the Win98 Command Line.

Comment: Yeah, that occurred to me fifteen seconds later. They still make USB floppy drives? :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to boot the virtual machine from the floppy?

If not, it should be sufficient to just copy the files and folders from the floppy into a folder of the virtual machine (via shared folders or network file sharing). Then when you're in the virtual machine you can bring up its command line and run the driver setup files (or add references to the driver in CONFIG.SYS and/or AUTOEXEC.BAT, if that's what it requires).

Comment: Nope. I don't need a bootable. I'd rather e-mail the files than network them in Win98, though.

Answer (score 1):

The [FreeDOS version of DISKCOPY](http://www.freedos.org/software/?prog=diskcopy) can both read and write image files as well as actual floppy disks ([direct link to ZIP file](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/micro/pc-stuff/freedos/files/dos/diskcopy/0.9/dskcp095.zip)). It is licensed under the GNU General Public License.

Example usage:

```
diskcopy a: drivdisk.img
```

Answer (score 0):

Many Linux Installation CDs used to contain the RawWrite.exe command line  and RawWriteWin.exe Windows GUI program.  Have rawwrite save floppy disk image to a file and use that in VirtualBox.  *The OP and ftp searches indicate rawwrite does not have dd functionality to write to a file.  This will not work.*  There exist dd.exe i would think can run at the Win98 command line ... wonder if an old mingw could.

If you have an old Linux install CD, i would check it for a DOSUTILS folder.

A better DOS/Win98se executable may be from this installation.
http://ftpsek.com/browser/mirrors.kernel.org/mandrake/Mandrakelinux/official/10.2/i586/dosutils/

i suspect the following website could help as well.

> http://www.chrysocome.net/rawwrite

Comment: Neither RAWRITE.EXE nor RAWRITE2.EXE nor RAWRITE3.EXE can save an image file of a floppy disk. Only RawWriteWin (the GUI program) can.